# Create sub List from List in Java that's not a single continuous range

Tags: java, list, collections, sublist

Suppose I have the code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");  //want
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");  //want
list.add("E");  //want
```

and I'd like to create a new list that only has the elements "A", "D", E".

The List class has a method subList that will work if you only have 1 single continuous range, but what if you want multiple ranges, or multiple discrete elements?

Is there any method in java or library that allows me to do something like:

```
List<String> subList = NeatListUtilities.subList(list, 0, 3, 4);
```

Comment: It'd be easy to implement.  I was just wondering if Java had it, or if some commonly used library had it.

Comment: A valid point, but consider that Apache Commons provides a lot of functions that would be easy to implement ourselves.  But if we've got a lot of these "little" functions we implement ourselves, it starts to snowball.  The library I'm requesting seems to be something that would be commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

None that I know of, however it is fairly simple to implement.

(No error / range checking, assumed use of ArrayList)

```
public static <T> List<T> subList(List<T> src, int... indices) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(indices.length);
    for(int i : indices) {
        result.add(src.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to do what you want with `Stream`:

```
List<String> subList = IntStream.of(0, 3, 4)
    .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, probably you don't need a library for this.

Comment: Could also replace `i -> list.get(i)` with `list::get` if, like me, you find method references cleaner.